# Symfony 5: error loading bundle at extension's load method

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I am trying to understand the necessary steps for creating reusable bundles. I'm using Symfony 5.2 and PHP 8.0.

I have two sibling directories containing the projects `MainProject` and `FirstModule`.

`composer.json` for project `MainProject`:

```json
{
    "type": "project",
    "name": "modulartest/main_project",
    "license": "unlicense",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": [{
        "type": "path",
        "url": "../FirstModule/"
    }],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.0",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.12",
        "modulartest/first_module": "dev-master",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^6.1",
        "symfony/console": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.29",
        "symfony/yaml": "5.2.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "5.2.*"
        }
    }
}
```

`composer.json` for project `FirstModule`:

```json
{
    "type": "symfony-bundle",
    "name": "modulartest/first_module",
    "license": "unlicense",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.0",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^6.1",
        "symfony/console": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.29",
        "symfony/yaml": "5.2.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "ModularTest\\FirstModuleBundle\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "ModularTest\\FirstModuleBundle\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "5.2.*"
        }
    }
}
```

In projeto `FirstModule`, I implemented a service, and a controller that uses that serve, all too simple, just for testing.

Service code in `FirstModule\src\Controller\FirstController.php`:

```php
<?php


namespace ModularTest\FirstModuleBundle\Service;


/**
 * Class FirstService
 * @package ModularTest\FirstModuleBundle\Service
 */
class FirstService
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function now(): string
    {
        return 'First Service time: '.date('c');
    }
}
```

Code for controller in `FirstModule\src\Controller\FirstController.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace ModularTest\FirstModuleBundle\Controller;

use ModularTest\FirstModuleBundle\Service\FirstService;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * Class FirstController
 * @package ModularTest\FirstModuleBundle\Controller
 */
class FirstController extends AbstractController
{


    /**
     * FirstController constructor.
     * @param FirstService $firstService
     */
    public function __construct(private FirstService $firstService)
    {
    }

    /**
     * @return Response
     */
    #[Route('/first', name: 'modular_test_first_module_first')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->json([
            'message' => 'Welcome to your new controller!',
            'path' => 'src/Controller/FirstController.php',
            'date' => $this->firstService->now()
        ]);
    }
}
```

I tried to follow rigorously the instructions given by Symfony documentation in those three pages:

- https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles.html
- https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/best_practices.html
- https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/extension.html

Thus, I implemented bundle's class this way:

```php
<?php


namespace ModularTest\FirstModuleBundle;


use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

/**
 * Class ModularTestFirstModuleBundle
 * @package ModularTest\FirstModuleBundle
 */
class ModularTestFirstModuleBundle extends Bundle
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPath(): string
    {
        return \dirname(__DIR__);
    }
}
```

I implemented extension's class this way:

```php
<?php


namespace ModularTest\FirstModuleBundle\DependencyInjection;


use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;

/**
 * Class ModularTestFirstModuleExtension
 * @package ModularTest\FirstModuleBundle\DependencyInjection
 */
class ModularTestFirstModuleExtension extends Extension
{

    /**
     * @param array $configs
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader(
            $container,
            new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config')
        );
        $loader->load('services.yaml');
    }
}
```

And the content inside file `FirstModule\src\Resources\config\services.yaml` is as follows:

```yaml
# This file is the entry point to configure your own services.
# Files in the packages/ subdirectory configure your dependencies.

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    ModularTest\FirstModuleBundle\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
            - '../src/Tests/'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    ModularTest\FirstModuleBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller/'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
```

Ok, all that done, I ran the server in `MainProject` with `symfony server:start`, e there were no immediate errors. Then I tried to browser the route that points to the controller that was defined by the bundle, that is, `https://127.0.0.1:8000/first`, and I received this:

> FileLocatorFileNotFoundException
>
> #### The file "../src/" does not exist (in: "C:\Users\eu\dev\php\symfony\modulartest\FirstModule\src\DependencyInjection/../Resources/config").

This is the Stack Trace:

```
Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLocatorFileNotFoundException:
The file "../src/" does not exist (in: "C:\Users\eu\dev\php\symfony\modulartest\FirstModule\src\DependencyInjection/../Resources/config").

  at C:\Users\eu\dev\php\symfony\modulartest\MainProject\vendor\symfony\config\FileLocator.php:71
  at Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator->locate('../src/', 'C:\\Users\\eu\\dev\\php\\symfony\\modulartest\\FirstModule\\src\\DependencyInjection/../Resources/config', true)
     (C:\Users\eu\dev\php\symfony\modulartest\MainProject\vendor\symfony\config\Loader\FileLoader.php:117)
  at Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\FileLoader->glob('', true, array(object(FileExistenceResource)), false, false, array())
     (C:\Users\eu\dev\php\symfony\modulartest\MainProject\vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\Loader\FileLoader.php:176)
  at Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\FileLoader->findClasses('ModularTest\\FirstModuleBundle\\', '../src/', array('../src/DependencyInjection/', '../src/Entity/', '../src/Kernel.php', '../src/Tests/'))
     (C:\Users\eu\dev\php\symfony\modulartest\MainProject\vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\Loader\FileLoader.php:99)
  at Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\FileLoader->registerClasses(object(Definition), 'ModularTest\\FirstModuleBundle\\', '../src/', array('../src/DependencyInjection/', '../src/Entity/', '../src/Kernel.php', '../src/Tests/'))
     (C:\Users\eu\dev\php\symfony\modulartest\MainProject\vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\Loader\YamlFileLoader.php:671)
  at Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader->parseDefinition('ModularTest\\FirstModuleBundle\\', array('resource' => '../src/', 'exclude' => array('../src/DependencyInjection/', '../src/Entity/', '../src/Kernel.php', '../src/Tests/')), 'C:\\Users\\eu\\dev\\php\\symfony\\modulartest\\FirstModule\\src\\DependencyInjection/../Resources/config\\services.yaml', array('autowire' => true, 'autoconfigure' => true))
     (C:\Users\eu\dev\php\symfony\modulartest\MainProject\vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\Loader\YamlFileLoader.php:234)
  at Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader->parseDefinitions(array('parameters' => null, 'services' => array('ModularTest\FirstModuleBundle\' => array('resource' => '../src/', 'exclude' => array('../src/DependencyInjection/', '../src/Entity/', '../src/Kernel.php', '../src/Tests/')), 'ModularTest\FirstModuleBundle\Controller\' => array('resource' => '../src/Controller/', 'tags' => array('controller.service_arguments')))), 'C:\\Users\\eu\\dev\\php\\symfony\\modulartest\\FirstModule\\src\\DependencyInjection/../Resources/config\\services.yaml')
     (C:\Users\eu\dev\php\symfony\modulartest\MainProject\vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\Loader\YamlFileLoader.php:154)
  at Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader->load('services.yaml')
     (C:\Users\eu\dev\php\symfony\modulartest\FirstModule\src\DependencyInjection\ModularTestFirstModuleExtension.php:30)
  at ModularTest\FirstModuleBundle\DependencyInjection\ModularTestFirstModuleExtension->load(array(array()), object(MergeExtensionConfigurationContainerBuilder))
     (C:\Users\eu\dev\php\symfony\modulartest\MainProject\vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\Compiler\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php:76)
  at Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder))
     (C:\Users\eu\dev\php\symfony\modulartest\MainProject\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\DependencyInjection\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php:39)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder))
     (C:\Users\eu\dev\php\symfony\modulartest\MainProject\vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\Compiler\Compiler.php:91)
  at Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile(object(ContainerBuilder))
     (C:\Users\eu\dev\php\symfony\modulartest\MainProject\vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\ContainerBuilder.php:736)
  at Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile()
     (C:\Users\eu\dev\php\symfony\modulartest\MainProject\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Kernel.php:541)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer()
     (C:\Users\eu\dev\php\symfony\modulartest\MainProject\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Kernel.php:780)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->preBoot()
     (C:\Users\eu\dev\php\symfony\modulartest\MainProject\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Kernel.php:183)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
     (C:\Users\eu\dev\php\symfony\modulartest\MainProject\public\index.php:20)
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there.  The error message was misleading since it indicated src was a missing file and of course it is a directory.  Plus it is obviously right there.  The error is actually coming from the autowire section in services.yaml.  You copied the lines from config/services.yaml but failed to account for the fact that in a bundle the relative path to the src directory is different.

```
# first_module/src/Resources/config/services.yaml
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true

  ModularTest\FirstModuleBundle\:
    resource: '../../../src/' # Tweak the relative path
    exclude:
      - '../DependencyInjection/'
      - '../Entity/'
      - '../Kernel.php'
      - '../Tests/'

  ModularTest\FirstModuleBundle\Controller\:
    resource: '../../../src/Controller/'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

I find it easier to trouble shoot these sorts of wiring problems from the command line.  I just make a console command in main project and injected FirstService into it.

You don't need Bundle::getPath().  Probably had that in there when debugging.

Be aware that if these bundles are truly meant to be shared across multiple applications then autowiring is discouraged.  It works but you might want to consider just manually defining services like the other bundles do.

By the way, I had forgotten about using the path attribute for repositories in composer.json.  So thank you for that.  Seems to work better than a symbolic link.

Comment: Thank you! After making those changes, I got a new error:  ===> Expected to find class "ModularTest\FirstModuleBundle\Resources\config\bundles" in file "C:\Users\ACJP\dev\php\symfony\modulartest\FirstModule\src\Resources\config\bundles.php" while importing services from resource "../../../src/", but it was not found! Check the namespace prefix used with the resource.

Comment: Hmmm. It might be wise to become familiar with Symfony before getting bogged down in the details of how to do something outside of the normal workflow.  In particular, maybe take a look at how autowire works as well as how googling error messages often turn up useful results.  Finally, ask yourself what exactly does bundles.php accomplish in a bundle?  I was more than willing to help you get past a misleading error message especially since I wanted to test the repositories path attribute.  But that is as far as I want to go.

Comment: Well, I must recognize your help, and it would be obnoxious of me to demand more. The case is, I've been writing modular applications in python/django for a while and now I was put in another team where php/symfony is required. With all my respect for all the qualities I know symfony has, it's been way harder for me to understand its system. Deadlines make me anxious as well, but this is not your fault at all. So, thank you for the moment, especially for taking your time with a post that was already downvoted. This was very kind. Have a nice week!

Comment: Hopefully you have figured out that you need to add Resources to the excluded directories in order to prevent autowire from trying to create a service from any .php file it happens to find.

Comment: Thank you, @Cerad. But if I do that, then I get this error:  No route found for "GET /first"

Comment: Guess I woke up in a better mood today.  No lecture about reading the docs or searching for answers.  Just take a look at config/routes/dev/web_profiler.yaml for an example of how to load routes from a bundle.  Use bin/console debug:router to test your work.  And I would strongly suggest checking out the [symfonycast tutorials](https://symfonycasts.com/).

Comment: thank you again. You have my word I read the docs and searched for answers. I'm new to the framework and this must be preventing me from grasping what seems to be obvious for many programmers. I'm feeling quite dimwit about this, I admit, but I assure you I'm not lazy. I'll keep on trying until I get it right.For the moment, I can only thank you for your help.

Comment: Keep in mind that you are starting out by trying to do a fairly advanced configuration.  Something that relatively few Symfony developers do on a routine basis.  Back when Symfony 2 was first released, using bundles was quite common.  But it turned out to be a big stumbling block for new developers so the need for bundles was reduced.  Instead of starting with bundles it would have been better to just build an app, become familiar with the framework and then refactor if you felt the need.

Comment: Thank you, @Cerad. May I ask you for a last piece of advice? My problem is: I need a "central" backend app that implements a custom user and a custom JWT authentication (it imports user data from another webservice, including permission levels, that is, roles). This I did, it's ready. But I need to build a module template (a bundle?) so other developers can implement easily plugable packs of services, entities and controllers independently, checking user roles given by the "central" backend. That's why I chose bundles from the start. Should I insist, or there's a better way? Thank you so much.

Comment: Look at it this way.  Imagine if someone with a very basic knowledge of python and no experience at all with django came to you and asked how to setup an enterprise application based on some rather sketchy specifications.  There is a Symfony Reddit board where these sort of vague questions might have a better chance.

Comment: Just a note about `config/routes/dev/web_profiler.yaml`. As I didn't find it in my project, I discovered that it only appears if `symfony/web-profiler-bundle` is installed as a dev dependency. But running `symfony new` won't install it by default. `symfony new --full` will, though. Or we must install it via `composer require --dev`. I guess.

Comment: ok, I totally understand and I will ask this question there. Thank you again.